# Preparing an agent for the job. Agent not running on Devops

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget-package

I have a dev ops pipeline that used to work, so that when I push my source code the project builds.

I am using the hosted agents.

However at the moment I get a message

> Preparing an agent for the job
>
> An agent is ready for the job Connecting...

[image: An agent is ready for the job]

and nothing further happens.
If I click Summary I can see that the Build pipeline has not started.

I think that it may have to do with a 3rd party custom nuget package source being offline and am wondering steps to troubleshoot.

Here is the azure-pipelines.yml

```
    pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.403


- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config

    nugetConfigPath: 'MyApi/mynuget.config'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore

    projects: '**/Api*.csproj'




#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.projects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'


#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.projects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish

    publishWebProjects: false

    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Here is mynuget.config ( obfuscated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="3rdparty" value="http://nuget.devweb.3rdparty/nuget" />
    <add key="SBDCommonFeed@Local" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myproject/_packaging/myfeedFeed@Local/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- Others -->
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <!-- secret stuff -->
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

I tried commenting out the 3rd party package source in mynuget.config but it did not help.

Comment: I expect I need to wait for the 3rd party to come back on line or organise an alternative feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not do anything wrong. The message of

> Preparing an agent for the job

is the issue on our side.

[image]

This is the issue which started from around 1.5 hours ago because I faced this error also.

Just wait some time, our team is fixing this issue to recover the normal work of Hosted agent use.

For public users, please refer to this link to get the event anouncement: https://status.dev.azure.com/_history. (Seemed it hasn't been updated to public because of delay).

Comment: Thanks. However I get a 401 when I click your link.

Comment: @KirstenGreed, forgive my missing. I provided you the notification link which private to our internal. Updating the screenshots to my answer.

Comment: @KirstenGreed, The hosted agent available now on my side, what about yours? Not sure whether the releases has deployed to your region.

Comment: Thanks It is now failing due to the missing Nuget package... rather than stalling.

Comment: @KirstenGreed, welcome:-) Look like you have got normal work. so now, you can get steps to troubleshoot the package missing error by analyzing the detailed build log?

Comment: Yes. Gotta get my 3rd party help :-)